# Converting Nested JSON to nodes and links structure in JavaScript with different keys

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, graph, tree

I would like to convert my raw JSON array data of the form

```
      "data": {
        "name": "Sint Maarten",
        "introduction": {
          "background": "Although sighted by Christopher COLUMBUS in 1493 and claimed for Spain, it was the Dutch who occupied the island in 1631 and began exploiting its salt deposits. The Spanish retook the island in 1633, but the Dutch continued to assert their claims. The Spanish finally relinquished the island of Saint Martin to the French and Dutch, who divided it between themselves in 1648. The establishment of cotton, tobacco, and sugar plantations dramatically expanded African slavery on the island in the 18th and 19th centuries; the practice was not abolished in the Dutch half until 1863. The island's economy declined until 1939 when it became a free port; the tourism industry was dramatically expanded beginning in the 1950s. In 1954, Sint Maarten and several other Dutch Caribbean possessions became part of the Kingdom of the Netherlands as the Netherlands Antilles. In a 2000 referendum, the citizens of Sint Maarten voted to become a self-governing country within the Kingdom of the Netherlands, effective October 2010. On 6 September 2017, Hurricane Irma hit Saint Martin/Sint Maarten, causing extensive damage to roads, communications, electrical power, and housing. The UN estimated the storm destroyed or damaged 90% of the buildings, and Princess Juliana International Airport was heavily damaged and closed to commercial air traffic for five weeks."
        },
        "geography": {
          "location": "Caribbean, located in the Leeward Islands (northern) group; Dutch part of the island of Saint Martin in the Caribbean Sea; Sint Maarten lies east of the US Virgin Islands",
          "geographic_coordinates": {
            "latitude": {
              "degrees": 18,
              "minutes": 4,
              "hemisphere": "N"
            },
            "longitude": {
              "degrees": 63,
              "minutes": 4,
              "hemisphere": "W"
            }
          },
```

to something of the form

```
{"nodes":[{"id":'Sint Maarten'},{"id":'Hemisphere'}, {"id": "N"}, {"id":"E"}], "links": [{source:"Sint Maarten", target:"Hemisphere"}, {source:"Hemisphere", target: "N"}, {source: "Hemisphere", target: "E"}]}
```

So I can visualise it as a tree structure like this

```
Sint Maarten ---> Hemisphere ---> [N,E]
             ---> Language ---> [Language 1, L2, L3]
```

and so on.

I have tried a manual approach where I first flattened the entire JSON object array recursively into 1D and added all the elements into the nodes but I'm stuck in trying to get the links right, since the data is structured in a way that `key` fields are unique for each entry. I am trying to have a tree structure like it is in the desired output.

I would like to know if there's any technique by which this can be achieved since my source JSON array is nested so I would like to have the algorithm for `links` to take in account of the nested hierarchy. of my source file, so I can generate a summary form for my entire dataset of world's countries.

Any pointers on how this algorithm could be achieved would be really appreciated.

EDIT: This is my current approach

```
let rawData = fs.readFileSync('./database/factbook.json')
let picker= JSON.parse(rawData)

let arr= {}
arr['name'] = picker['name']
arr['hemisphere'] = [picker['geography']['geographic_coordinates']['latitude']['hemisphere'], picker['geography']['geographic_coordinates']['longitude']['hemisphere']]
arr['area'] = '/'
...
...
```

I am trying to create an array with the desired output I would like to have, since the raw file contains over 300 parameters but I'm interested in only 20 of them. And once I get this array I need to convert the key value pairs into `node` and `links` structure which should take account of the case where values of a particular key is an array, for example

```
key: [a,b,c]
```

then my expected output in `links` should be

```
key --> a
key ---> b
key ---> c

``
```

Comment: can you share your code how far you tried to solve the problem

Comment: @maziyank updated to include code

Comment: Your example doesn't really make sense to me. What is the (well formed) input and what is the output? Currently this is not clear since the output contains data that the input doesn't contain etc

Comment: @vincent Apologies for not being clear. Basically I have a nested JSON array of world countries with historic, geographic and demographic data for each country for which I had posted a snippet of how the dataset looks like. It has parameters like language, region etc. which I need to cherry-pick and construct a tree structure based on the nodes-links structure

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow! Here is a more generic answer using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan), since you didn't give too much detail.

You should be able to use this as a starting point! Please feel free to ask any questions!

```js
// const lodash = require('lodash');
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = [{ name: 'Sint Maarten', introduction: { background: '... long text ...' }, geography: { location: '... long text ...', geographic_coordinates: { latitude: { degrees: 18, minutes: 4, hemisphere: 'N' }, longitude: { degrees: 63, minutes: 4, hemisphere: 'W' } } } }];

const convert = (() => {
  const logic = {
    '[*].name': ({ value, context }) => context.nodes.push({ id: value }),
    '[*].geography.geographic_coordinates.{latitude,longitude}.hemisphere': ({ value, parents, context }) => {
      context.nodes.push({ id: 'Hemisphere' });
      context.nodes.push({ id: value });
      context.links.push({ source: parents[parents.length - 2].name, target: 'Hemisphere' });
      context.links.push({ source: 'Hemisphere', target: value });
    }
  };
  return (haystack) => {
    const r = objectScan(Object.keys(logic), {
      breakFn: (kwargs) => {
        kwargs.matchedBy.forEach((needle) => logic[needle](kwargs));
      }
    })(haystack, { nodes: [], links: [] });
    r.nodes = lodash.uniqWith(r.nodes, lodash.isEqual);
    r.links = lodash.uniqWith(r.links, lodash.isEqual);
    return r;
  };
})();

console.log(convert(data));
/* => {
  nodes: [
    { id: 'Hemisphere' },
    { id: 'W' },
    { id: 'N' },
    { id: 'Sint Maarten' }
  ],
  links: [
    { source: 'Sint Maarten', target: 'Hemisphere' },
    { source: 'Hemisphere', target: 'W' },
    { source: 'Hemisphere', target: 'N' }
  ]
}
 */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/lodash@4.17.20"></script>
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.9.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)